# Wait for Socket.io response in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have been working on this problem for a long while, but still can't seem to figure it out. I have a client (or rather a proxy in this case) that should provide a function that returns a userlist. The userlist exists on a server, and should be served on request via socket.io.

Here is what I currently have:

as the client:

```js
async function getUserList(){
        return new Promise( (resolve) => {
            socket.on('connect', async function (data) {
                socket.emit('getData', 'users');
                socket.on('data', async function (response) {
                    var response = await response;
                    if (response) {
                        resolve(response);
                    }
                    else {
                        reject(response);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    };
function getUserList1(){
  getUserList().then(function(response){
    return response;
  }).catch(function(error){console.log(error);})
}
```

or updated:

```js
getUserList = async function() {

  const getUserList1 = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    socket.on('connect', data => {
      socket.emit('getData', 'users');
      socket.on('data', response => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  });

  console.log('Receiving data');

  const users = await getUserList1(); // Waits here until it is done.

  console.log('Data received: ', JSON.stringify(users));
  return users;
};

var newUsers = getUserList();
console.log(newUsers)
```

and as the server:

```js
var users  = { Foreador: '1234',
     mudito: '1234',
     troll: '1234',
     josocxe: '1234'
   };
var subjects = ["Primer tema", "Segundo tema"];

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
  socket.on('getData', function(data){
  console.log("the request received:", data)
  if (data == "users"){
   io.emit('data', users);
   console.log("sending back users")
  }});
 socket.on("sendData", function(data){
   console.log("the data received:", data)
   users = data
   console.log("Final users: ", users)
  })
  });

http.listen(3000, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:3000');
});
```

The code itself works, but if I call getUserList1 I receive first undefined and then later I can log the result. I know that its against the asynchronous nature of JS, but I want to directly receive the result (that is the requirement of the exercise and I dont really see any other way to do it).
I have so far tried do achieve this with callbacks as well as promises, but did not succeed.
So, does anybody know how I could halt the code execution until I have received the response from the server?
I hope I have explained myself and thanks for your help!

Comment: What is getUserList3 ? I dont see that function anywhere in your code

Comment: Corrected it, now the function names should be correct

Comment: It is not possible in JavaScript to turn the result of an asynchronous operation into a synchronous result. The best you can do is return the promise from `getUserList1` and handle the result in a `then` function.

Comment: Could you give me an example how you mean that? Another `then` would only propagate the issue further, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah

First of all, the point of using socket is that you would have a reactive software that can listen to changes.

So, whenever there is a change, you can do something about it.

Look an example:

```
function initializeSocket() {
    const socket = ...;
    socket.on('connect', data => {
      socket.emit('getData', 'users');
      socket.on('data', newUsers => 
        renderUsers(newUsers)
      );
    });
  });
}

function renderUsers(users) {
  .
  . // Here could handle some render logic
  .
}
```

That's the way the event driven architecture works, simple as that.

But, if you need to wait for some async call from the server, I would recommend you to provide an endpoint in your server for it, so you could call it and wait for the response.

Like this simple express example:

```
app.get('/users', (req, res, next) => 
  res.json(users)
)
```

and on the client side:

```
const users = await fetch(api_url + '/users')
```

Comment: I agree that using the HTTP protocol would be more suitable here since there is no continuous communication between client and server.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to use `async` / `await` to store your result in a variable. You are already doing it in some parts of your code so you are familiar. You could use an [async IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/async_function) to make your current scope able to use the `await` keyword.

Below I've made an example with a simplified version of your `getUserList` function and a single variable which calls the value with the `await` keyword. This will halt the execution of the rest of the function scope until `getUserLists` resolves. Now you can use the result from the `getUserList` function in the `user` variable.

```
(async function() {

  const getUserList = () => new Promise(resolve => {
    socket.on('connect', data => {
      socket.emit('getData', 'users');
      socket.on('data', response => {
        resolve(response);
      });
    });
  });

  const users = await getUserList(); // Waits here until it is done.
  // Continue all your code after this.

}());
```

Comment: Firstly thanks for the help! But the problem is that yes, with this code I can store the userlist in a variable, but it happens after the function has been executed (the `await` does not seem to do the trick here). I want to return `users` directly to the calling function, but if I return it here I just return a promise. Do you know how to wait for this promise to resolve before returning anything? Another `.then()` is again just `undefined` or a `promise`

Comment: I get what you are saying. It is because you are implementing your code differently than the example above. An [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) calls itself and requires nothing from you to get it going. And the reason for using it is to use `async` / `await` in the "global" scope. Your implementation however does require you to call it.

Comment: Also, when you add `async` to a function it will automatically return a `Promise`.

Comment: async/await doesnt work with sockets,as man above says,better is to make endpoint and use http for thaat kind of server check.